# Can't display errors in attachment_fields_to_save

Tags: custom-field, attachment-fields-to-edit

I am writing a plugin for adding a custom field to the image attachment dialogue box, the plugin works for storing valid input data. I have a problem for showing the error message "This is not a valid URL".

I think that I followed the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_save) correctly but maybe there is something that I still missing.

```php
class my_plugin {

    public function __construct( ) {

        $this->url_pattern = "/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?" .
"([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|" . 
"%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]" . 
"|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/";

        add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", array($this, "videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_edit"), 10, 4);
        add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", array($this, "videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_save"), 10, 5);

    }

    public function videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post) {

        $form_fields["videourl"]["label"] = __("Video URL");
        $form_fields["videourl"]["helps"] = "Set a video URL for this image";

        $form_fields["videourl"]["input"] = "text";
        $form_fields["videourl"]["value"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videourl", true);

        return $form_fields;
    }


    function videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {

        if( isset($attachment['videourl']) ){

            if( mb_strlen ( trim($attachment['videourl']) ) > 0 && preg_match($this->url_pattern, trim($attachment['videourl']))){
                update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_videourl', $attachment['videourl']);
            }elseif(mb_strlen ( trim($attachment['videourl']) ) == 0){
                delete_post_meta($post['ID'], '_videourl');
            }else{
                $post['errors']['videourl']['errors'][] = __('This is not a valid URL.');
            }
        }

        return $post;
    }
}
```

Comment: I confuse of yours _"the plugin works until comes to show an error message"_, what works? what the error? could you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, storing valid input data is ok, doesn't show the error message "This is not a valid URL." when the data is not ok.

Comment: thanks for clarify, have you read a "Note" in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

At the time this is a known bug

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30687

Answer (score 0):

In **Edit Media**, if we look the admin notice on update attachment, it use redirect function to handle those notice. So, basically we can still handle those error with redirect function too, then hook [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices).

Here my approach how to handle error in screen `attachment` Edit Media.

```
class my_plugin {

    public function __construct( ) {

        $this->url_pattern = "/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?" .
"([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|" . 
"%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]" . 
"|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/";

        add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", array($this, "videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_edit"), 10, 4);
        add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", array($this, "videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_save"), 20, 2);

        /**
         * Hook admin_notices
         *
         */
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'admin_notices' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Fire admin_notices function to show message
     *
     */
    public function admin_notices()
    {
        global $current_screen;

        /**
         * Check current screen
         *
         */
        if ( 'attachment' == $current_screen->id )
        {
            if ( isset( $_GET[ 'error' ] ) && 1 == absint( $_GET[ 'error' ] ) )
            {
                /**
                 * HTML format to show notices
                 *
                 */
                printf ( '<div id="message" class="%1$s notice is-dismissible"><p>%2$s</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">%3$s.</span></button></div>',
                    'error', //type error or updated
                    __( 'Your Error Messages.', 'text-domain' ), //your error text
                    __( 'Dismiss this notice', 'text-domain' ) //for close button
                );
            }

            /**
             * Remove query parameter 'message' and 'error'
             *
             */
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( array( 'message', 'error' ), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        }
    }

    public function videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post) {

        $form_fields["videourl"]["label"] = __("Video URL");
        $form_fields["videourl"]["helps"] = "Set a video URL for this image";

        $form_fields["videourl"]["input"] = "text";
        $form_fields["videourl"]["value"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videourl", true);

        return $form_fields;
    }


    public function videourl_image_attachment_fields_to_save( $post, $attachment ) {

        if ( isset( $attachment['videourl'] ) )
        {
            if ( mb_strlen ( trim($attachment['videourl'] ) ) > 0 && preg_match($this->url_pattern, trim($attachment['videourl'] ) ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_videourl', $attachment['videourl'] );
            } elseif( mb_strlen ( trim($attachment['videourl']) ) == 0 ){
                delete_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_videourl' );
            }

            /**
             * Handle error if empty 'videourl'
             *
             */
            if ( empty( $attachment['videourl'] ) )
            {
                /**
                 * Build error query for redirection
                 *
                 */
                $location = add_query_arg(
                    array(
                        'error' => 1
                    ),
                    $post['_wp_http_referer']
                );
                wp_safe_redirect( $location ); // wp-admin/post.php?post={id}&action=edit&error=1
                exit;
            }
        }

        return $post;
    }
}
```

You can change the code suit your needs. It look like a little bit tricky but I hope this helps.